# vue: making the username variable accessible to all components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an app that logs in users using github.

I've implemented a component that logs in the user and then emits an event with the username when successful to the parent.

But now I also have other components that need access to the username in order to work. for example, a component that lists the repositories of the signed in user.

I could include the variable as a prop separately for each component. But that seems "WET". I was thinking that a better approach would be to make a global variable named `username` that is accessible to all.

I've looked into vue instance variables, but those (correct me if I'm wrong) read only, and therefore cannot be updated when the user signs in.

How can I approach this?

Comment: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) will be one good choice.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of problem that Vuex comes to solve. You can setup a store that holds the user with it's email, username, etc.
As an alternative, if you don't wish to add Vuex into your project just to store the user you might want to store it in the main `App`/`Root` component.
You also can try to create a Vue plugin, see the first paragraph:
`1. Add some global methods or properties`
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html